# Scala Compare Map value to another Map key

Tags: scala

I have two Maps:

```
val myMap1 = Map(
    testKey1 -> List(testValue1, testValue2, testValue3....), 
    testKey2 -> List(testValue4, testValue5, testValue6....),
    testKey3 -> List(testValue7, testValue8, testValue9....)     
    testKey4 -> List(testValue10, testValue11, testValue12....)     
)

val myMap2 = Map(
        testValue1 -> List(Value1, Value2, Value3....), 
        testValue5 -> List(Value4, Value5, Value6....),
        testValue10 -> List(Value7, Value8, Value9....)
    )
```

And I wanted to create a third Map by matching Map1 values to Map2 Keys,

Where Map1 keys will be the Key and Map2 values will be the value of this new third Map.

It would be like this

```
val myMap3 = Map(
        testKey1 -> List(Value1, Value2, Value3....), 
        testKey2 -> List(Value4, Value5, Value6....),
        testKey4 -> List(Value7, Value8, Value9....)
    )
```

I am failed to iterate over the Map1 values which is a list and get the corresponding key of that value.

Comment: Why is `testKey3` dropped and `testKey4` kept? What's the logic for that?

Comment: The values of the `testKey3` is not in the key of  `myMap2`

Comment: Ah, got it. So what happens when `testValueX` appears under 2 or more keys?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get what you want by using `mapValues` on the first **Map** to get each **List** of values' keys, and then use `flatMap` on this lis to get the desired values.
Here is an example, please note the `getOrElse` method, to ensure we always get a value, even if the key does not exists.

```
val myMap1 = Map(
  "testKey1" -> List("testValue1", "testValue2", "testValue3"), 
  "testKey2" -> List("testValue4", "testValue5", "testValue6"),
  "testKey3" -> List("testValue7", "testValue8", "testValue9"),
  "testKey4" -> List("testValue10", "testValue11", "testValue12")     
)

val myMap2 = Map(
  "testValue1" -> List(1, 2, 3), 
  "testValue2" -> List(5), 
  "testValue5" -> List(4, 5, 6),
  "testValue10" -> List(7, 8, 9)
)

val myMap3 = myMap1.mapValues {
  valuesList => valuesList.flatMap {
    valueKey => myMap2.getOrElse(valueKey, List.empty[Int])
  }
}

// myMap3: Map[String, List[Int]] = Map(
//   testKey1 -> List(1, 2, 3, 5),
//   testKey2 -> List(4, 5, 6),
//   testKey3 -> List(),
//   testKey4 -> List(7, 8, 9)
// )
```

If you need to remove the keys with empty values you can filter after.
 `myMap3.filter { case (_, values) => values.nonEmpty }`

## Edit

> If I want to create this myMap3 where the value will be myMap2's key and their respective value.

Given the values of `myMap1` are a list of **keys** for `myMap2`, I think what you really want is a `Map[String, Map[String, List[A]]`.

```
val myMap4 = myMap1.mapValues {
  valuesList => valuesList.map {
    valueKey => valueKey -> myMap2.getOrElse(valueKey, List.empty[Int])
  }.toMap
}

// myMap4: Map[String, Map[String, List[Int]]] = Map(
//   testKey1 -> Map(testValue1 -> List(1, 2, 3), testValue2 -> List(5), testValue3 -> List()),
//   testKey2 -> Map(testValue4 -> List(), testValue5 -> List(4, 5, 6), testValue6 -> List()),
//   testKey3 -> Map(testValue7 -> List(), testValue8 -> List(), testValue9 -> List()),
//   testKey4 -> Map(testValue10 -> List(7, 8, 9), testValue11 -> List(), testValue12 -> List())
// )
```

Again, you can filter empty values if you don't need them.

```
val myMap5 = myMap1.mapValues {
  valuesList => valuesList.flatMap { // here we use flatMap, to filter any None.
    valueKey => myMap2.get(valueKey).map(values => valueKey -> values)
  }.toMap
} filter {
  case (_, values) => values.nonEmpty
}

// myMap5: Map[String, Map[String, List[Int]]] = Map(
//   testKey1 -> Map(testValue1 -> List(1, 2, 3), testValue2 -> List(5)),
//   testKey2 -> Map(testValue5 -> List(4, 5, 6)),
//   testKey4 -> Map(testValue10 -> List(7, 8, 9))
// )
```

Comment: Nice, but can be condensed: `myMap1.mapValues(_.flatMap(myMap2.get))`

Comment: @jwvh well, I prefer to be explicit with names, instead of using `_` _(but, as I said is just my personal taste)_. However, since you use `get` the `flatMap` will return a `List[List[A]]` instead of a plain `List[A]` _(which is what I believe op needs)_, of course one can call `.flatten` after the `flatMap`, but I think is just an unnecessary extra iteration.

Comment: @LuisMiguelMejíaSuárez thank you so much. it's working perfectly. Though I am very new in scala and functional programming its little bit harder the code to me. 

I have one more question, If I want to create this myMap3 where the value will be myMap2's key and their respective value.

Like this :

`val myMap3 = Map(
        testKey1 -> testValue1 -> List(1, 2, 3, 5),
        testKey2 -> testValue5 -> List(4, 5, 6),
        testKey4 -> testValue10 ->List(7, 8, 9)
    )`

Comment: @AshiqurRahman I've updated the answer, hope it helps. If you have any other simple question, don't doubt in asking it as a comment - however, if the question implies another change in the logic of the code, I believe the best would be to ask another question on the site. As an advice I recommend you to take any introductory course in Scala, you will find that thinking in terms of `map`, `flatMap` & `filter` instead of _iterate_ to transform collections is not that hard - also, for me it helps a lot think in terms of types, what I have as input VS what I want as output, and the code flows.

Comment: @LuisMiguelMejíaSuárez thanks a lot for your reply and the advices. i will follow it sire